# PHP echoed rows uniquely expandable/collapsible rows

Tags: javascript, php

I've figured out most of it, namely the uniqueness part, I seem to be having a problem with sequencing.

I am using two different photos for the up/down arrow buttons, initially one of them is not displayed eg. display: none; but I can't seem to trigger this at the right time after the rows are echoed eg. when they exist.

So I want to hide all of these buttons when the rows are pulled, and then change them per row when I need to. This part I believe I have figured out, it is the initialization. I get a null error eg. they don't exist when trying to call the hide function after the rows have been pulled.

I tried to trigger it upon submit and I also tried to trigger the function by echoing after the rows displayed, doesn't work.

Is there a way to do inline hide on an image eg. inside the  tag?

Basic layout:

echo rows by php

```
echo 
'<div class="hideme" id="'.$id_db.'container">'.
$content_to_be_displayed.
'</div>'.
'<div class="buttons"><img src="" id="'.$id_db.'down" width="" height="">'.
'<img class="hideme" src="" id="'.$id_db.'up" width="" height="">'.
'</div>'.
'<br>'.
'<script>hideButtons();</script>'
;
```

This results in multiple rows with a source looking like:

```
<div id="12container">content1</div><div class="buttons"><img src="" id="'.$id_db.'down" width="" height=""><img class="hideme" src="" id="'.$id_db.'up" width="" height=""></div>

<div id="98container">content2</div><div class="buttons"><img src="" id="'.$id_db.'down" width="" height=""><img class ="hideme" src="" id="'.$id_db.'up" width="" height=""></div>

// etc...
```

So I can identify each row uniquely via the echoed id concatenated with a word and then all of them can be identified by class using jQuery:

```
<script>
function hideButtons() {
$(".hideme").css('display', 'none');
}
</script>
```

The position of the script has been moved from above the rows to below, maybe that is irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the `style` attribute? `style="display:none;"` on the image tag?

Comment: Hahaha, thank you. That was so easy. Thanks again.